# How to choose the delimiter for splitting text into columns?

Tags: google-sheets, import-from-csv, csv

I have a DSV file and each row corresponds to one instance/piece of text as normal. Specifically, I have my own delimiter `###` instead of the default (i.e., comma `,`). However, when I open the DSV by using Google Sheets, these tools always display the DSV file by splitting automatically by default delimiter. It causes a mess because some columns may contain several commas.

How can I disable the trigger that splits the text into columns automatically and only use my own delimiter?

My DSV is like below:

```
a###b###c###d,e,f,g###h,",",j
h###i,j,k###l###m###n,"[o,p]"
q,r###s###c,u###v,w###x,y,'z,'
```

As suggested, I have tried to copy the content directly to a newly created Google sheet, however, I got the error as below due to the size of the content.

> There was a problem
>   Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell.

Comment: You realise CSV is short for *comma*-separated values - right?

Comment: Excel doesn't really like multi-character delimiters - could you use pipe "|" or thorn "Þ" instead? <hold ALT and number pad 0222 - release ALT>

Comment: the major question is: **how you import your CSV data into Google Sheets?** copy-paste?

Comment: In Google sheets you can type import in help and it'll go to a basic import - mostly looking for html or xml formats, but flat file is there too.

Comment: @player0 Good point, I uploaded my CSV file to Google drive and open it by Google sheet. I have tried to copy-paste the content directly to a newly created sheet but got an error updated in my question.

Comment: @Bowen your Q in it's current form is unanswerable because it's based on a false premise.  Your opening statement is _I have a CSV file..._.  Well, you don't.   You have a `###` Separated File.  Any attempt to use built in CSV handlers are doomed to fail.  For a reusable solution,  I suggest you build your own custom file import utility, in VBA or GoogleScript, to implement your custom file format requirements

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I generalized the question by using term DSV (Delimiter-separated values) instead of CSV (comma-separated values). And I believe google sheet should be able to handle DSV (i.e., not limited to use comma as delimiter).

Comment: @ross Sry, my case is DSV rather than CSV. Question updated.

Comment: @Bowen, great, but I still think you need to norrow it down a bit.   Excel or Google,  pick one (the answers will be different).  One off or reusable (if one off I can can give you an option for Excel, vs reusable,  write your own handler)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Appreciate. I picked google-sheet and updated my question.

Comment: @Bowen great, sorry I can't be of any more help, Google-sheet is not my area of expertise

Answer (score 3):

With File > Import > Upload > Drag one can choose one's delimiter (though not, as far as I am aware, as in Excel the option to "Treat consecutive delimiters as one"):

[image: Sheets Impor.]

So, depending upon your specific file, you may find the result this way is what you want - provided you are prepared to delete a couple of blank columns for each set of `###` (if not choosing a single character rather than `###` in the first place).

Comment: nice answer; if you are trying to open log ( specially, AWS ALB access log, which is space delimited), make sure you convert a.log ---> a.txt

Answer (score 0):

if you import your CSV data into Google Sheets via copy-paste you can press this combo right after importing it:

1. <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`D`**</kbd>
2. <kbd>**`E`**</kbd>
3. <kbd>**`ARROW UP`**</kbd>
4. <kbd>**`ARROW UP`**</kbd>
5. <kbd>**`ENTER`**</kbd>

and type in your **`###`**

[image: 0]

Comment: it's a good idea and I am sure it will work for small scale of content. But it does not work for my case because I cannot copy-paste directly to sheet due to an error updated in my question. Thx!

Comment: @BowenXu I see. do you paste it into active cell < that may be the reason why you get 50000 limit error - or paste over selection ?

Comment: also, is your cvs dataset 2D-compatible? - meaning, if you could fit your data into one cell, are there any means how to split it in two directions? rows + columns. an example would be: `♥1#2#3♥4#5#6` which could be split by `♥` into rows and then by `#` into columns. asking coz there are ways how to bypass 50000 cell limit...